# Quantum circuit error in QISKIT

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-circuit

I am trying to build a simple 16-qubit Quantum circuit where I am appending an 8-qubit quantum circuit to the first 8-qubits of my custom circuit. Then I measure all the qubits.
However when I execute it, I get the error:

**DAGCircuitError: expected 8 wires, got 16**

(See attached image).

Any help on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I see you write `simpleAlgo16` but the gate on the drawing states `algo8`. Is there a chance that `algo8` gate actually expects 8 inputs?

Comment: No, apart from the fact that it is jus a label, it is named algo8 because the output (to next stage in the computation) is just 8 qubits).